# Image is not taking the full height of the div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to make the image fit perfectly such that there is no purple extension below it.

[image: The Image is having a purple line below it showing that is not fitting perfectly.]

```css
.myImg {
  background-color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
}
#officeImg {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="myImg">
  <img
    id="officeImg"
    src="images/image-header-desktop.jpg"
    alt="Office-Image"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Using `width: 100%; height:100%` inside `.myImg` CSS definition?  Could you try it?

Comment: `height:100%` and `object-fit:cover` should work.

Comment: I tried it . The image is protruding out of the div.

Comment: @Kokodoko I tried it. It is the same as masterguru

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: block` to the CSS rule for the image itself (`#officeImg`). The default setting aligns the image on the baseline (i.e. the line on which letters are placed), which creates the space you are seeing because there is some space below the baseline for letters like y, g, p etc.

`display: block` avoids that.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the exact same project when I was learning CSS so I can provide you my solution on that one.

This was the whole HTML:

```
    <div class="card">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Get <strong>insights</strong> that help your business grow.</h1>
        <p>
          Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions
          regarding revenue, customer experience, and overall efficiency.
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>10k+ <span>companies</span></li>
          <li>314 <span>templates</span></li>
          <li>12m+ <span>queries</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS of the card (container):

```
.card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 60%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: var(--card-bg);
}
```

and the image:

```
.content,
.image {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
  background: linear-gradient(
      hsla(277, 70%, 40%, 0.5),
      hsla(277, 64%, 40%, 0.5)
    ),
    url("./images/image-header-desktop.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

.myImg {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 80vw;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.myText {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="myText">hello world</div>
    <div class="myImg"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```